# Writing this HTML Control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to write this HTML Dropdown control in ASP.NET with the runat=server tags to retrieve its selection in the code behind. I'm a bit confused how to add the runat tags and make it an ASP control.

```
<div class="wrapper-demo" style="margin-left:0;">
          <div id="dd2" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1">
            <span>To :</span>
              <ul class="dropdown" tabindex="1">
                  <li> <a href="#"> Arabic </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#"> Bengali </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#"> Chinese </a> </li>
                  <li> <a href="#"> Czech </a> </li>
              </ul>
       </div>
   ​</div>
```

Can yall help out a bit?

Comment: Try this `<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: umm.. the CSS classes? @PradnyaBolli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to this code:

```
<div class="wrapper-demo" style="margin-left:0;">
    <div id="dd2" class="wrapper-dropdown-1" tabindex="1">
    <span>To :</span>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDown1" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Arabic" Value="0" />   
        <asp:ListItem Text="Bengali" Value="0" /> 
        <asp:ListItem Text="Chinese " Value="0" /> 
        <asp:ListItem Text="Czech " Value="0" /> 
    </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
​</div>
```

However ASP.NET will render `select` element, not `ul` list.

Comment: Doesn't work. A very messed up drop down list appears inside the HTML drop down list

Comment: because you need to change your css class to properly style a `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Request.Form["Control Name"]".
Please find attached Example [Link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-selected-value-of-HTML-Select-DropDownList-in-ASPNet-code-behind-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)